# Setting Up SFTP Service with Public Key Autentication and PGP

Tags: linux, debian, sftp, pgp

My final goal is to create a SFTP server coupled with a PGP authentication as described here : [SFTP+PGP](https://xcesstek.wordpress.com/2012/10/21/setting-up-sftp-service-with-public-key-autentication-and-pgp-support/)

Actually i succeeded to create an user called **sftp_user** who can connect to his own  directory on my server via SFTP with his username and password.
(I followed this great procedure [Setting up SFTP](https://memo-linux.com/mettre-en-place-un-serveur-sftp-sous-debian-8/) )

Now, i want to allow him to connect with a key file generated by PGP without using a password.

I've already generated a PGP key but i can't assign it to my user **sftp_user**.

So what is the procedure for achieve this ?

For information, i'm using a VPS on Debian Stretch 9.2. I can only connect in SSH for setting up the environment

Comment: Why not use ssh keys for that and configure public key authentication, maybe plus a ssh-agent on the local machine? Either way, this question is off topic here as it's not about programming. Try https://unix.stackexchange.com instead.

Comment: thx for the answer .
In fact i can't choose the way the user will connect. It's a customer's prerequisites
Thx for the advise , i'm gonna post it there